# Rails migrations add a column and reference it to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

`mysql> desc Tab_A;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Tab_B_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |`

With the above schema, I can do `Tab_A.first.tab_b` to get the respective `Tab_B` details.

To add Column `option_A` to Table `Tab_A` and reference that column to Model `Tab_C`

Migrations change updated to -->

`add_reference :Tab_A, :option_a, references: :Tab_C`

With that I got a column `option_a_id` which referenced the table Tab_C's ID.

But,
In the action -->
`Tab_A.first.tab_c` gives an error and I can only access `Tab_A.first.tab_c_id`.

I know I'm doing something wrong, big time. Not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget to add `belongs_to` association to `Tab_C` in `Tab_A` model. You should use something like this:

```
class TabA < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :tab_c
  ...
```

check it.

Comment: I can only access Tab_A.first.option_a_id NOT Tab_A.first.option_a.Tab_C

Answer (score 0):

You need to have these [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in your models:

```
class TabA < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tab_c

class TabC < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tab_a
```